# A tight bound for $T(n)=2^nT(\frac{n}{2})+n^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Given  recurrence
$$T(n)=2^nT\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+n^n$$
How we can show that $T(n)\leq n^n$?

I show that $T(n)\geq n^n$ because of existence the term $n^n$ in $T(n)$.

Comment: So $T(n/2)= 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

As

$$
T\left(2^{\log_2 n}\right)=2^n T\left(2^{\log_2 n - 1}\right)+n^n
$$

Calling $\mathcal{T}\left(\cdot\right) = T\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right)$ and $z = \log_2 n$ we have the "equivalent" recurrence

$$
\mathcal{T}\left(z\right)= 2^{2^z} \mathcal{T}\left(z-1\right)+(2^z)^{2^z}
$$

now as the recurrence is linear

$$
\mathcal{T}_h\left(z\right)= 2^{2^z} \mathcal{T}_h\left(z-1\right)
$$

has the solution

$$
\mathcal{T}_h\left(z\right)=4^{2^z}c_0
$$

so choosing $\mathcal{T}_p\left(z\right)=4^{2^z}c_0(z)$ after substituting in the complete recurrence we get

$$
c_0(z)-c_0(z-1) = \frac{\left(2^z\right)^{2^z}}{4^{2^z}}
$$

with solution

$$
c_0(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{z-1}\frac{\left(2^{k+1}\right)^{2^{k+1}}}{2^{2^{k+2}}}
$$

and then

$$
\mathcal{T}\left(z\right)= 4^{2^z}\left(c_0 + \left(\sum_{k=0}^{z-1}\frac{\left(2^{k+1}\right)^{2^{k+1}}}{2^{2^{k+2}}}\right)\right)
$$

and to recover $T(n)$ is sufficient to substitute $z = \log_2 n$